# If I know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1+x}{x} = 1$, can I just "multiply through" by $x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

If I know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1+x}{x} = 1$, can I just "multiply through" by $x$ to conclude $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1+x) = x$? I am worried about violating limit rules. I viewed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932973/multiplying-both-sides-of-an-equation-when-theres-a-limit-on-one-side) similar math.StackExchange question but the answers are not fully in agreement and rather complicated.

Comment: Your original limit isn't $1$, though.

Comment: That limit is not $1$ but it does not exist.

Comment: You would have a contradiction if you multiplied by $x$: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (1+x) = x \implies 1=0$.

Comment: **Never, ever** claim $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ is anything other than a constant (or non-existent); it's not a non-constant function of $x$, which is just a dummy variable. What you _can_ write is $f(x)\sim g(x)$ as $x\to a$. (As several people already noted, the example you have in mind is wrong.)

Comment: Suppose I were to start out a question with, "If I know that $1 = 0,$ can I ... ." How would you answer such a question? This is the kind of question you have asked here, namely, what happens if you "know" a fact but actually the fact is false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this. In a limiting expression like $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1+x}{x}$, the variable $x$ is a *dummy* variable (also called *bound* variable, or *local* variable in programming) that exists only within the limit expression $\frac{1+x}{x}$ itself. You cannot multiply by $x$ from the outside; $x$ doesn't exist there.